# How to decrypt password in Meteor

Tags: c#, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

is possible decrypt this type of password generated by Meteor application.

[image]

My idea is to use the same credentials (email and password) for my application in C #

[image]

Comment: That is not encrypted - it it a hash using BCrypt

Comment: C# can use bcrypt so it is a case of replicating your logic in C#

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in other answers, you cannot decrypt the passwords, but you can very well use the Meteor database to authenticate in a different system.

This is how to do it:

In your other system, first find libraries that provide `SHA256` and `bcrypt` implementations.

Then take the password as entered by the user, and first compute a SHA256 digest hash from it.

Then feed this hash string to bcrypt using number of rounds = 10 (This is the Meteor default).

Now compare the result from bcrypt with the `services.password.bcrypt` from the MongoDB database of Meteor. If they match, the user provided the correct password.

For reference, the Meteor implementation [is here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js). It is quite simple and well commented.

Answer (score 2):

The very purpose of hashing and encrypting your password is to make decrypting them unpractical.

However, you can reuse the bcrypt(hash(password)) from your meteor app and check against it in another application, provided you use the same scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Is that a bcrypt hash? It depends on the size of the key as Blowfish as a variable sized key. If it's 32 bits. Sure, you could do it with some serious computing power and a few hours. It it is a 128bit key, you'd be long long dead (and so would the universe as we know it) before it every finishes brute forcing. Blowfish does have a minor vulnerability for weak keys though. I would rethink your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar use case where I was writing a C# application that would validate users created through a Meteor.js application. The code I got to work was this (using System.Security.Cryptography and BCrypt.Net-Next):

```
string sha256_hash(string value) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using (SHA256 hash = SHA256.Create()) {
        Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
        Byte[] resultingHash = hash.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(value));

        foreach (Byte b in resultingHash) {
            stringBuilder.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

// First compute SHA256 hash
string sha256hash = sha256_hash("my_password");

// Let BCrypt.Net rehash and check if it matches Meteor's hash
if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(sha256hash, dbPassword) == true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Valid!");
}
```